# What is the cost of converting 32-bit integer to double for Intel and AMD architecture?

Tags: intel, amd-processor

I'm under the impression that conversions back and forth between these two representations are not expensive operations on modern hardware, is this true?

Comment: About .03 cents per conversion.

Comment: With respect to @Joachim Sauer, $0.0003 is a rip-off. I'll do it for $0.0001/conversion.

Comment: If you run it on windows, you can probably measure it (c Linus Torvalds)

Comment: @Michas I could probably have it working over small vectors.

Answer (score 1):

[Intel says](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-floating-point-to-integer-conversions/) that it can be rather expensive (on a Pentium 4 with Visual C++ 6), but using Intels' VTune performance analyser, you can turn the heavy, slow, _ftol call with a single FISTP FPU instruction for a 5x performance gain.

Then they say that enabling SSE2 instructions will give you an 11x performance gain, but I hear that has a high latency penatly. There's further speed up for [using SSE3](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-implement-the-fisttp-streaming-simd-extensions-3-instruction/).

So, I'm not sure what the performance is like nowadays, although I think SSE2 is enabled by default in VC++, I'm pretty sure it is in GCC.